# Spark RDD External Storage

Tags: csv, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, rdd, master-slave

I have written a python code `sum.py` on summing up all numbers for each csv file in a directory `data`. Now I am going to use Apache-Spark on Amazon Web Service (AWS), to parallelize the summation process for each csv file. I have already done the following steps:

1. I've created one master and two slave nodes on AWS.
2. I used the bash command `$ scp -r -i my-key-pair.pem my_dir root@host_name` to upload directory `my_dir` onto the AWS cluster master node. The folder `my_dir` contains two sub-directories: `code` and `data`, in which, `code` contains the python code `sum.py`, and `data` contains all csv files.
3. I've login my AWS master node, and from there used the bash command `$ ./spark/copy-dir /my_dir/code/` to send my code directory `code` that contains `sum.py` to all slave nodes.
4. On AWS master node, I've also put the directory `data` containing all csv files into the HDFS using `$ ./ephemeral-hdfs/bin/hadoop fs -put /root/my_dir/data/`.

Now when I submit my application on AWS master node: `$ ./spark-submit ~/my_dir/code/sum.py`, it shows up an error that the worker node cannot find the csv files. However, after I send my data directory `data` to all slave nodes using command `copy-dir`, everything works perfectly.

So I get very confused about this problem. As far as I know, the driver program on master node loads the csv files, creates the RDD and sends separate tasks as well as the RDD to each of the slave nodes. That means the slave nodes don't need to know the original csv files, as they just receive the RDD from the master node. If this true, why should I send all my csv files to each of the slave node? Also, if I send all my csv files to the slave nodes, much external disk storage on slave nodes is gonna be used. Does it mean Apache-Spark is a very costly tool for parallel computing? I really appreciate it if anyone helps me on these two questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to make data available to all nodes. However, each node will try its best to load only the data it is concerned with (its *partition*), and you can [tune the level of parallelism](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#level-of-parallelism) to best fit your task. There are many ways to make this data available to all nodes besides copying it on each node's file system. Consider using a distributed file system, like [HDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html), or hosting your files in an accessible location from each node, which includes [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or a file server.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But it seems that I am still confused about the architecture of the whole process. I know that the driver program on master node loads the csv files, creates the RDD and sends the RDD to each of the slave nodes. So the slave nodes just receive the RDD generated from the master node and then do its own task, but why should I send my csv files to each of the slave node? (As they've get the RDD) Also, as I mentioned in my question, I've also put the directory `data` containing all csv files into the HDFS in my step 4, why do I have to copy all my data to the slave nodes?

Comment: To be caricaturally simple, the driver creates the RDD, but the RDD is not the data you put in your collection, only metadata on how to access it. As the means for accessing that data, seen from your driver, is to look on the local file system, this is what the executors, driven by the same metadata, will do.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! It seems that in Apache-Spark, the dataset being processed later still occupy much external storage, no matter we use the master node file system, HDFS or AWS S3. But I do not understand why we call that in-memory stored.

Comment: If you use HDFS, or S3, or a file server, or any way of serving the data which is accessible from any node with a single point of access, there is no need to replicate data on every node.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I also have another question based on this. Does each slave node load data from its own local file system or from HDFS? If it loads data from its local file system, why do we need to put data into HDFS before we submit to run? Are there any reasons?

Comment: If you have another question, perhaps you may want to ask it as a question on this site, so that it can be useful to others (and that people reading this question are not the only ones to answer). Nothing prevents you then to answer this comment with a link to the newly-created question.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I posted a question on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31578986/load-data-using-apache-spark-on-aws/31580277#31580277