# Load Data using Apache-Spark on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, filesystems, hdfs

I am using Apache-Spark on Amazon Web Service (AWS)-EC2 to load and process data. I've created one master and two slave nodes. On the master node, I have a directory `data` containing all data files with csv format to be processed.

Now before we submit the driver program (which is my python code) to run, we need to copy the data directory `data` from the master to all slave nodes. For my understanding, I think it is because each slave node needs to know data file location in its own local file systems so it can load data file. For example,

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

### Initialize the SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("ruofan").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

### Create a RDD containing metadata about files in directory "data"
datafile = sc.wholeTextFiles("/root/data")  ### Read data directory 

### Collect files from the RDD
datafile.collect()
```

When each slave node runs the task, it loads data file from its local file system.

However, before we submit my application to run, we also have to put the directory `data` into the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) using `$ ./ephemeral-hdfs/bin/hadoop fs -put /root/data/ ~`.

Now I get confused about this process. Does each slave node load data files from its own local file system or HDFS? If it loads data from the local file system, why do we need to put `data` into HDFS? I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what's the issue here. If your data is available on s3, why are you trying to put it on hdfs?

Comment: Just a typo. Have already fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify for others that may come across this post.

I believe your confusion is due to not providing a protocol in the file location. When you do the following line:

```
### Create a RDD containing metadata about files in directory "data"
datafile = sc.wholeTextFiles("/root/data")  ### Read data directory
```

Spark assumes the file path **/root/data** is in HDFS. In other words it looks for the files at **hdfs:///root/data**.

You only need the files in one location, either locally on every node (not  the most efficient in terms of storage) or in HDFS that is distributed across the nodes.

If you wish to read files from local, use **file:///path/to/local/file**. If you wish to use HDFS use **hdfs:///path/to/hdfs/file**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One quick suggestion is to load csv from S3 instead of having it in local.

Here is a sample scala snippet which can be used to load a bucket from S3

```
val csvs3Path = "s3n://REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_ACCESS_KEY:REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_SECRET_KEY@REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_S3_BUCKET"
val dataframe = sqlContext.
                    read.
                    format("com.databricks.spark.csv").
                    option("header", "true").
                    load(leadsS3Path)
```

Comment: Actually, I know there is a way to use S3, and I'm also familiar with how to do. My question is that does each slave nodes load data from its own local file system or from HDFS? If it loads data from its local file system, why do we need to put data into HDFS before we submit to run?

Comment: @RuofanKong That's just a suggestion as you are running everything AWS, it is better to have the CSV in S3.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! In fact, I know its better to use S3... The reason I post the question here is I want to clarify the concept of loading file process so everyone who has the same question may get help, instead of only choosing the better way... So far I think I still have the question: Does each slave nodes load data from its own local file system or from HDFS? If it loads data from its local file system, why do we need to put data into HDFS before we submit to run? I really appreciate for helping me solve the conceptual question.

Comment: I've not worked on spark with HDFS. But conceptually when you file in HDFS you don't need to have the file present in each nodes local file system. You can just read the file like `text_file = spark.textFile("hdfs://...")`. Likewise,  when you want to read the file from local file system, each nodes should have the files in same directory and it is not required to be part of HDFS. You can just load it something like `spark.textFile("/home/user/somefile.csv")`. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#external-datasets

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. Yeah, I totally agree with you. I understand the whole thing as I've read this tutorial more than 10 times. But when you run spark on AWS, it's different. I really don't understand why I have to put the local files into HDFS if I use the local file system. If you wanna use the local file system, but not putting the file into HDFS, it will generate error! It's very strange. That is the reason why I post my question here......... I really want to know the concept behind this problem... I hope you understand what I mean...

Comment: Yeah I got your concern, I don't know that to use local file system we have to upload same file into HDFS. That's weird. So far I've just worked with Spark reading from S3. So someone working similar to what you are working may have better answer